# How many external Conditional stylesheet do you use for Internet Explorer in your web projects?

Tags: css, cross-browser

How many external **IE** Conditional Style-sheets do you use for Internet Explorer in your web projects?

See this page before to answer : http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Answer (score 0):

I usually have one for IE6, and one for IE7. I haven't had the need for an IE8 specific stylesheet, and having a separate stylesheet for all versions of IE isn't really practical.

Comment: But if you need something for IE 6 and 7 both then you will have to write and  keep and maintain in both css.

Comment: True, but that scenario is pretty rare, I find that IE6 and 7 usually require different hacks so I don't end up with too much redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE]>
 global css for all IE's
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
 css for specific version
<![endif]-->
```

yes you have two files but it's ok for me =) usually you just test global one, does this works nice in both versions, if not, then just put it in specific version css =)

btw with this script http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ I usually have no issues in ie7

Comment: `<!--[if IE]>` it will affect to all other current and future version of IE.